# fail2ban datepattern regex

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I am trying to match this datepattern in fail2ban:

```
test.example.org 12.100.3.45 - - [14/Jun/2019:13:54:50 +0000] "GET
```

Can use the regex tester:

```
fail2ban-regex -d ^%%d/%%M/%%Y:%%H:%%M:%%S "test.example.org [14/Jun/2019:13:22:57 +0000] 1.2.3.4" "<HOST>"
```

I expect the ip adres to be found but the date patern is not found.

```
Running tests
=============

Use      datepattern : {^%d/%M/%Y:%H:%M:%S}
Use   failregex line : <HOST>
Use      single line : test.example.org [14/Jun/2019:13:22:57 +0000] 1.2.3.4


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
[processed in 0.00 sec]

|- Missed line(s):
|  test.example.org [14/Jun/2019:13:22:57 +0000] 1.2.3.4
```

UPATE:

I use a my.conf file :

```
# fail2ban filter configuration for nginx proxy
# hk

[Definition]


failregex = ^<HOST> - [^-[ ]+.+HTTP/1.[0-9]" 401

ignoreregex =

datepattern = ^%%d/%%M/%%Y:%%H:%%M:%%S
```

When using the datepattern like this I get a error in the regex parser.

The way I understand fail2ban works is by taking the datepattern and convert it is a regex expression that looks for dates. So the datepattern is not a valid? regular expression I believe(as Sean points out in the comments).

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : nginx-proxy-auth, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : ^Day/Minute/Year:24hour:Minute:Second
Use         log file : /data/docker/nginx-proxy/logs/access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fail2ban-regex", line 34, in <module>
    exec_command_line()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 685, in exec_command_line
    if not fail2banRegex.start(args):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 635, in start
    self.process(test_lines)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 458, in process
    line_datetimestripped, ret = self.testRegex(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 409, in testRegex
    ret = self._filter.processLine(line, date)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/server/filter.py", line 526, in processLine
    (timeMatch, template) = self.dateDetector.matchTime(l)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/server/datedetector.py", line 373, in matchTime
    match = template.matchDate(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/server/datetemplate.py", line 153, in matchDate
    self._compileRegex()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/server/datetemplate.py", line 147, in _compileRegex
    raise e
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/server/datetemplate.py", line 144, in _compileRegex
    self._cRegex = re.compile(self.regex)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 765, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 759, in _parse
    raise source.error(err.msg, len(name) + 1) from None
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'M' as group 6; was group 3 at position 107
```

So this pattern tries to find `minutes` instead of `Months`

Comment: That is not a regular expression

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the first thing to note is that the ^ symbol anchors the datetime to the start of the string, which isn't valid in your case, so you should remove the ^.

Answer (score 1):

In the fail2ban datepattern, `M` matches minutes, as indicated. If you want to match numerical month, use `m`; if you want to match the three-letter abbreviation, use `b`.

You can also match the nanos with `%f`, but the `+` needs to be escaped.

> So the datepattern is not a valid? regular expression

The datepattern is a valid regex it just was matching the wrong thing. However I think your failregex was also too vague (`"<HOST>"` would just match literal `"1.2.3.4"`). It needs to be something like `".*<HOST>"` or `"<HOST>$"` to have an idea of where to look for the IP.

So putting this all together to match your intended pattern, you could use:

```
fail2ban-regex -d "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S \+%f" "test.example.org [14/Jun/2019:13:22:57 +0000] 1.2.3.4" "^.*<HOST>"
```